# Jquery how to synchronizely compute total when user filtered the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that can filter content and automatically compute the total based on the result. I'm hiding the rows that didn;t  meet the search criteria.

my problem is there's a delay when synchronizing the total 
Notice in my code snippet, however when i add another key stroke it synchronize the total correctly.

what i want to achieve is to calculate everyting on Basic pay row synchorizely whenever user start filtering.

Thank you in advance :)

```js
function myFunction() { // my function in table filter
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

$(function() { // my function in summarizing basic pay
  $('#myInput').on('keydown', function() {

    var regAreaIs = 0;
    $('#myTable tbody tr:visible').each(function(index) {
      if ($('.reference_col').css('display') != 'none') {
        console.log("Row: " + index + " >Display is visible");
        $(this).find("#bpay").each(function() {
          var reg = $(this).text();
          regAreaIs += parseFloat(reg);
        }); // end loop
      } else {
        console.log("Row: " + index + " >Display is none");
        $(this).find("#bpay").each(function() {
          var reg = $(this).text();
          regAreaIs += parseFloat(reg);

        }); // end loop
      }
    });

    $('#totalResult').text(regAreaIs); // displaying the total 
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background: #ddd;
}

tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">



<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:30%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
      <th style="width:20%;">Basic Pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Anne</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td id="bpay">512</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Philippines</td>
      <td id="bpay">560</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Alvin</td>
      <td>Korea</td>
      <td id="bpay">600</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Jasmine</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td id="bpay">700</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <th>Total:</th>
    <th></th>
    <th id="totalResult">0</th>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keydown`. On `keydown`, the value of the input field has not yet been updated.

```js
function myFunction() { // my function in table filter
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

$(function() { // my function in summarizing basic pay
  $('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {
    var regAreaIs = 0;
    $('#myTable tbody tr:visible').each(function(index) {
      if ($('.reference_col').css('display') != 'none') {
        console.log("Row: " + index + " >Display is visible");
        $(this).find("#bpay").each(function() {
          var reg = $(this).text();
          regAreaIs += parseFloat(reg);
        }); // end loop
      } else {
        console.log("Row: " + index + " >Display is none");
        $(this).find("#bpay").each(function() {
          var reg = $(this).text();
          regAreaIs += parseFloat(reg);

        }); // end loop
      }
    });

    $('#totalResult').text(regAreaIs); // displaying the total 
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background: #ddd;
}

tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">



<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:30%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
      <th style="width:20%;">Basic Pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Anne</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td id="bpay">512</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Philippines</td>
      <td id="bpay">560</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Alvin</td>
      <td>Korea</td>
      <td id="bpay">600</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="reference_col">
      <td>Jasmine</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td id="bpay">700</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <th>Total:</th>
    <th></th>
    <th id="totalResult">0</th>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Comment: hi robby,  thank you so much saving my day it worked :)